# Simple Blob Detector

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to use cv2.SimpleBlobDetector() with this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

im = cv2.imread("owmla.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector()
keypoints = detector.detect()
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

but when I run it I get the error:
Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change:

`cv2.SimpleBlobDetector()`
to
`cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create()`

and do not forget to feed `im` to

```
keypoints = detector.detect(im)
```

also see:
[How to fix cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68964996/how-to-fix-cv2-error-unknown-c-exception-from-opencv-code)